# Why do Powershell queries on remote machine throwing access denied errors?

Tags: powershell, permissions, wmi

I'm getting such errors from the PowerShell ISE when I execute simple PowerShell queries on my machine connecting to a remote machine:

```
Get-WmiObject : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
At line:8 char:43
+                     $WmiOS = Get-WmiObject <<<<  -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName    $targetComputer -credential $credential    
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-WmiObject], UnauthorizedAccessException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:9 char:45
+                     $WmiOS.ConvertToDateTime <<<< ($WmiOS.LastBootUpTime)            
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (ConvertToDateTime:String) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

However, the same queries would work on my other team member's machine (or on any other machine) without any issues.

An example of the script that we're trying to execute:

```
                $WmiOS = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $targetComputer -credential $credential    
                $WmiOS.ConvertToDateTime($WmiOS.LastBootUpTime)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it work if you run it outside of Powershell ISE? Do you use the same account on the other machines?

Comment: Hi Lars: From my machine, it doesn't work at all whether by ISE or the shell. The account I'm using is not an issue since I can RDP into the machines without issues. I tested the same script on my coworker's box and it works for them both via ISE and shell.

Comment: so with their account on their machine it works? How about your account on their machine or their account on your machine? This will help figuring out if it is your account or your machine.

Comment: My account works there as well. Trying their account on my machine, the scripts utterly fail.

Comment: So it is fair to assume it is something on your machine. What is different from other machines? Since it uses DCOM it might be related to that.

Comment: WMI's security is finicky, so these kind of unexpected denials aren't uncommon. Can you browse the target machine over the network with `wbemtest.exe`, using the same account that's failing in your script?

Comment: if is a Dcom issue will give error from any computer using same script.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the below flags to the Get-WmiObject command:

```
-Authentication PacketPrivacy -Impersonation Impersonate
```

Answer (score 0):

Check firewall on remote machine and/or credentials to be in administrators local group of  remote computer

Comment: are operative system the same?

Comment: No, it's not the firewall since it connected successfully and got an explicit "Access Denied" error. It wouldn't have succeeded in connecting if the firewall was blocking WinRM.

Comment: @ewall: yes will be an rpc unavailable error. really strange issue. If I well understood same script from another computer querying wmi of same target computer it works!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the script you are running is not located on the server itself.  It is common practice for people to host their powershell scripts on the server in order to have them in various locations.  If your scripts are local, then you should be able to shut down the machine.